# not able to add kali to bootloader

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have installed linux kali using following link on youtube. www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLj2yQPWZDk

I completed the installation but in the end i am not able to add kali to bootloader. Easybcd software used gives me error shown in image below
[image]

while adding entry into the easy bcd option are not selectable(locked) as shown below.
[image]
Is it possible for me to add kali into the UEFI botloader anyhow. what are other options if any? my current OS is windows 10 with EFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootloader is locked. There are ways around this, but you could kali's bootloader instead - GRUB, which is more suited to these sort of things anyways. I think you can do this simply by changing your boot order through your BIOS to first boot the Kali partition.  Then you must add the windows partition to the GRUB boot list.

Once you are in Kali and everything is set up, including sudo priveliges for your user, open a terminal and enter this command:

```
lsblk
```

Find drive label (sdXY, where X is a letter and Y is a number)  for your Windows partition. "lsblk -f" can also be useful here.

Then run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

You are now editing a file.  Add this to the bottom of the file, replacing sdXY with what you found above:

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sdXY)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

TRIPLE check that this is that what you entered is the same as it is here.
Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot. Profit.

If you have any problems running any of the two sudo commands, it may be an SELinux permissions issue.  Run this:

```
sudo echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

then retry the command(s), then reboot or re-enable SELinux:

sudo echo 1 > /selinux/enforce

---

Alternatively, you could run Kali linux in a virtual machine on windows, eg. virtualbox